# Disabling manual input in dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to only have the calendar to specify my textbox input, and not permit keyboard-punched numbers in my calendar textbox, inside dijit.form.DateTextBox. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't any of the answers solve your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually ended up using something else - here is my solution:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
            dojo.query(".dijitDateTextBox input[role='textbox']").forEach(function (node, index, arr) {
                node.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
            });

        });
```

By setting the elements I needed to "readonly", I get the desired effect. I execute this on my page loads, I'm not sure about the overhead, but the main point is, it works.

Answer (score 6):

The code below can be used to make `DateTextBox` read only:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
       data-dojo-id="effectiveDate" 
       type="text" 
       name="effectiveDate" 
       id="effectiveDate" 
       data-dojo-props="'readonly': 'readonly'"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Sudhir : if you set the widget to disabled then you can't select a date on the calendar either.

Try this :

```
dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("yourcalendarid"), "onKeyPress", function(evt){
        dojo.stopEvent(evt);
    });             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add disabled parameter to your input:

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" 
  constraints="{datePattern:'MM/dd/yyyy'}"  
  value='' disabled
  validate='return true;'
/>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer from MrZombie in the extended widget you can add:

```
 //to disable input from user at the textbox.s
                        startup:function(){
                            this.inherited(arguments);
                            dojo.connect(this, "onKeyPress", function(evt){
                                dojo.stopEvent(evt);
                            });   

                        },
```

At the startup of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you can use to disable the dojo date input element.

**Code**

1) Use the `setDisabled(true)` method

```
dijit.byId('id').setDisabled(true);
```

*or*

2) Set `disable` the property directly. (You'll need to disable both elements)

```
dijit.byId(id).disabled = true;
dijit.byId(id).textbox.disabled = true;
```